# Open "Signatures and Stationary" window in Outlook using C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, interop, ms-office

I am using C# to create a program which opens Outlook settings. I managed to open Outlook new Email Message with VS Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook reference. The main thing for me to do is to open "Signatures and Stationary" window (as showed in picture). How can I do this?

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //Code for opening "Signatures and Stationary" window.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Changed signature tag to email tag. Please validate the exact meaning of tags on StackOverflow if there tags may have multiple meanings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to show that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var window = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();

        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        foreach (dynamic dialog in app.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.Application.Dialogs)
        {

            if (dialog.CommandName.Equals("EmailSignatureOptions"))
            {

                dialog.Show();

            }

        }

        app.Quit();
```